# Jupyter Notebook: multiple function calls only prints return for the most recently called function

Tags: python, function, class, jupyter-notebook, h5py

I'm trying to create a class to make viewing my data very quick and simple within Jupyter Notebook.

```
import color
import h5py

class h5view:
    tempf = h5py.File('juliadata\jul20160102_150km.001.hdf5', 'r')

    def data():
        print(color.YELLOW + 'Data' + color.END)
        templist = []
        for name in h5view.tempf['/Data']:
            templist.append(name)
        return templist
    def metadata():
        print(color.YELLOW + 'Metadata' + color.END)
        templist = []
        for name in h5view.tempf['/Metadata']:
            templist.append(name)
        return templist
```

This runs without any errors. In the next Jupyter Notebook Cell I type

```
h5view.data()
h5view.metadata()
```

outputs

```
Data
Metadata
['Data Parameters',
 'Experiment Notes',
 'Experiment Parameters',
 'Independent Spatial Parameters',
 '_record_layout']
```

But before Metadata there should be another returned list.  I tried it with other functions in the class (not listed above), and it always gives the return for the most recently called function, but not for any of the others.

If I were to just run `h5view.data()`
Then the output would be

```
Data
['Array Layout', 'Table Layout']
```

How do I stop the list here from disappearing the moment I call another function?

I tried assigning the function calls to variables, like so:

```
a = h5view.data()
b = h5view.metadata()
print(a, b)
```

which gives a new output:

```
Data
Metadata
['Array Layout', 'Table Layout'] ['Data Parameters', 'Experiment Notes', 'Experiment Parameters', 'Independent Spatial Parameters', '_record_layout']
```

Now the list I want is here, but it is after Metadata.  What I want is something that looks like this:

```
Data
['Array Layout',
 'Table Layout']
Metadata
['Data Parameters',
 'Experiment Notes',
 'Experiment Parameters',
 'Independent Spatial Parameters',
 '_record_layout']
```

Is there an easy way to do this, or perhaps another approach I should be taking?

Comment: Cause the notebook always only displays the return value of the last expression. (And whatever is explicitly printed, of course.)

Comment: The fact that *any* return value is printed is an artifact of the interactive interpreter you are using, not your code. If you want to see the output of both functions, call `print(h5view.data())` for the first one. (If you were running this as a script, you wouldn't see *either* return value without explicitly printing them.)

Answer (score 1):

Python notebooks only print a value if there is no code after it in the cell, which is why `h5view.data()` is not printing. To get the desired result just use print on each of them separately:

```py
print(h5view.data())
print(h5view.metadata())
```